# Change Startx Default on Slackware?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, xfce, slackware

I installed Slackware as a VM within Virtual Box. Host is Windows 7, if it matters. I have successfully installed guest additions and XFCE starts and runs cleanly with or without the guest additions. KDE however (which was set as the default for `startx`) starts well giving me the appropriate desktop at the appropriate resolution but crashes halfway during the splashscreen animation. I am not sure it is worth wrestling with it.

How do I change the default for `startx` to xfce? I realize that I can always start it at the command line with `startxfce4` at the command line but I may like to change the inittab run level to 5 which would trigger KDE with it's crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Slack provides "xwmconfig" to perform these changes.

You run this as user or root.

However XServer crashing may still be an issue with another X setting and not XFCE's fault. Make sure as well the VM has enough video memory and settings allow easy deployment of the desktop (I use 28MB).

Answer (score 1):

As per `man startx`, the following files control the behaviour of `startx`:

```
   $(HOME)/.xinitrc         Client to run.  Typically a shell script which runs  many  programs  in  the
                            background.

   $(HOME)/.xserverrc       Server to run.  The default is X.

   /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc   Client to run if the user has no .xinitrc file.

   /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc Server to run if the user has no .xserverrc file.
```

So, if you want to keep using `startx`, you should adjust the contents of your `.xinitrc` file.

But this might not be necessary, since heavyweight desktop environments such as KDE often come with ready-to-use startup scripts. In the case of KDE, there is one called **`startkde`** (I don't remember whether it is used as a replacement for `startx`, or you have to place it in `xinitrc`).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `~/.xsession` includes whatever it is that you want to start with `startx`. In this case:

```
echo startxfce4 >> ~/.xsession
```